# Can $8a^2+2$ be a square number, where $a\ge 1$ is an integer?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can $8a^2+2$ be a square number, where $a\ge 1$ is an integer?
Is there any method to prove or disprove it?

Comment: Removing the *algebraic-number-theory* tag.

Comment: Almost same as asking can twice a sum of squares be a square in a given case.

Answer (score 9):

No. Any squared integer number is either zero or one modulo $4$ , and in this case $\;8a^2+2=2\pmod 4\;$.

Quick proof: If $\;n\;$ is an even integer, then

$$n=2k\implies n^2=4k^2=0\pmod 4$$

and if it is an odd integer, then

$$n=2k+1\implies n^2=(2k+1)^2=4(k^2+k)+1=1\pmod 4$$

Comment: Thank you ! I knew the answer immediately after I had asked this question. How fool I was.

Comment: To the proposer: I have been in seminars and discussions with professors and grad students of math, and when someone asks a Q that is obvious or trivial (which happens!)  it is answered politely and without blame or ridicule.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Indeed so. Whom are you addressing? Who is "the proposer"?

Comment: The proposer is Zuo Ye.........